# Different formatting for section headers on even/odd pages in twoside document

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec, double-sided

I have copy-pasted a part of a code from this site that places `section` inside tikz to achieve the following result:

[image]

I want the rectangle around the text to start from the very gutter, i. e. from the left side of the *paper* on odd pages and finish on the right edge of the *text* (and just opposite for even pages). The name of the section should start from the position it is now in.

It is also worth mentioning that I want the rectangle near the gutter to be blue, and to be white near outer edge.

The trouble I am facing is that I don't know the gutter is located because I use `twoside` document. How can this be achieved?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inner=2in,outer=0.5in,bmargin=1in,tmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{calc}


\newcommand\SecTitle[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (A) [rectangle,left color=blue, right color=white, inner sep=4mm]%
    {%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth-8mm}%
        \LARGE\bfseries\raggedright\thesection\quad#4
        \end{minipage}
    };

    \end{tikzpicture}

}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\SecTitle{east}{west}{0\paperwidth}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Two}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\section{Test Section Three}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test Section Four}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition of `\SecTitle`, you can use `\ifodd\value{page}` to have different codes to be applied on even and odd pages, in the form

```
\ifodd\value{page}{
    odd format
}\else{
    even format
}\fi
```

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, so here is an example where I changed just a random couple of things from your code for even pages:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[inner=2in,outer=0.5in,bmargin=1in,tmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\SecTitle[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \ifodd\value{page}{%
    \node (A) [rectangle,left color=blue, right color=white, inner sep=4mm]%
    {%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth-8mm}%
        \LARGE\bfseries\raggedright\thesection\quad#4
        \end{minipage}
    };
    }\else{%
    \node (A) [rectangle,left color=white, right color=red, inner sep=4mm]%
    {%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth-8mm}%
        \LARGE\bfseries\raggedleft\thesection\quad#4
        \end{minipage}
    };
    }\fi%
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont}{}{0em}
{\SecTitle{east}{west}{0\paperwidth}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Tt Section Two}
\lipsum[2]
\clearpage
\section{Test Section Three}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Test Section Four}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]